# Want to know about the differences between the following topics:

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, factory

I researched a lot but I didn't understand the basic difference between the following topics. Please, tell me what is the basic difference between them and when to use them. And if possible please provide article links other than the Android developers guide. Thanks a lot!

1. ViewModel
2. AndroidViewModel
3. ViewModelProvider.Factory
4. ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory
5. ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to start by explaining the factories.

ViewModelProvider.Factory is necessary because the framework needs a way to be able to create instances of your ViewModel on your behalf, because it has to do this when returning from process death. You don't create instances directly yourself except inside the Factory.

The framework automatically provides some default factories that are capable of creating instances of your ViewModel if your ViewModel constructor's arguments are one of the following:

- `constructor()` Empty constructor (no arguments)
- `constructor(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle)`
- `constructor(application: Application)`
- `constructor(application: Application, savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle)`

So if your ViewModel constructor is like one of the above, you don't have to create your own ViewModelProvider.Factory. In your Fragment or Activity, you can simply use `private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()` to create it using the default factories.

You don't need to touch or even think about NewInstanceFactory or AndroidViewModelFactory. They are subtypes of Factory that the framework uses as the default implementations that can construct the above types of ViewModels.

---

AndroidViewModel is a ViewModel with an Application property. If your ViewModel constructor is like one of the last two in the list above and you want to avoid creating your own factory, you must subclass AndroidViewModel instead of ViewModel. The default factories for some reason will only handle those last two if your factory is an instance of AndroidViewModel. (Seems like an unnecessary and pointless restriction to me, but maybe I'm missing something.)